# Setting a VC.view appear inside the view of a parent VC not working for me

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to do something very simeple so I created a test project with a SingleViewApplication template.

In the ViewController.xib I added a child UIView to the main View.
I created a IBOutlet of type UIView and linked it to that view in the XIB.

I created a 2nd class and xib called TVC and changed the background color of it to blue so its noticeable when it appears.

In ViewController.m I went about making TVC appear, like so:

```
self.childView = [[TVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TVC" bundle:nil].view;
```

But nothing changes. 
I set a breakpoint in TVC method initWithNibName and it does get called.

What is it I've done wrong? I swear I have done this 10 times before in the past and it always worked. -.- What am I missing today?

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating the view controller but never actually doing anything with it. If you want to present it modally, use this:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[TVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TVC" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or if you just want to add the new controllers view to your current view, you need to use:

```
[[self view] addSubview:controller.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down.

Your first XIB creates your controller, creates it's childView and adds it as subview automatically when you create the first controller.

Then you create a second controller, take it's view and assign it to childView.

What's happening behind the curtains?
Your parent view controller still has the original childView added as subview, and since you never did `[self.view addSubview:self.childView];`, your TVC.view will never be shown.

**How to make it work:**
In order for this to work, you need to take out your childView from your parent controller's xib, and you can remove the `IBOutlet` tag off the property if you want.
Then, add this code:

```
self.tvc = [[TVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TVC" bundle:nil];
self.childView = [[TVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TVC" bundle:nil].view;
[self.view addSubview:self.childView];
```

And yes, you will need to store the controller somewhere. If you use the view and don't retain the controller anywhere, it will get released and you will start having bad access crashes